# How to get the difference between two integers

Tags: java, math, compare

I'm trying to make a program which uses areas and each area has an id (e.g.:1;1) and I'm trying to get the size of a specified area with comparing two ids but this method returns 1 as size.

```
 //Pos1 = -2;3 Pos2 = 0;1
 int x = Integer.valueOf(pos2.x).compareTo(pos1.x);
 int y = Integer.valueOf(pos2.y).compareTo(pos1.y);
 int size = Math.abs(x * y);
```

So how can I make this work?

Comment: `compareTo` always returns -1, 0, or 1 depending on the desired order of the two objects. Not sure if I understand the problem, but you might want to instead do something like `Math.abs(pos2.x - pos1.x)`, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result is 1 because `compareTo()` returns 0 if the arguments are equal, -1 if the first int is smaller than the second one and 1 if the second one is smaller (you can read more about it in the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#compareTo(java.lang.Integer))).

--> You should not use this method for this purpose. Calculate the difference instead:

```
int x = pos2.x - pos1.x;
int y = pos2.y - pos1.y;
int size = Math.abs(x * y);
```

Answer (score 10):

`compareTo` is not supposed to return the exact difference between two values. From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)):

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Use

```
int x = Math.abs(pos2.x-pos1.x);
int y = Math.abs(pos2.y-pos1.y);
int size = x * y;
```

Comment: thanks! just FYI, in the second line "Match" is wrong .. the correct word/class is "Math"

Answer (score 2):

Purpose of Integer.compareTo ( ) is not to find the difference between two Integer objects.  Its purpose is to specify the ordering between two Integer objects when they are sorted by Arrays.sort ( ) or Collections.sort( ).

You may find the difference in following ways:

```
int x = pos2.x - pos1.x;
int y = pos2.y - pos1.y;
int size = Math.abs(x * y);
```

Answer (score 1):

`compareTo` will return `-1` if `pos2.x` is smaller than `pos1.y`, `0` if they are the same, and `1` if `pos2.x` is greater than `pos1.y`.

Use this instead:

```
int size = Math.abs((pos2.x-pos1.x)*(pos2.y-pos1.y));
```

Comment: So what can I use?

Comment: If you want the dimensions of a certain area you can subtract pos2.x by pos1.x and pos2.y by pos1.y.